# WP7: How to show a toast?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I trying to use ShellToast as analog of the Android toast notification (without redirect). In one of examples:

```
        new ShellToast(){
            Content = "HerContent",
            Title = "MyTitle",
            NavigationUri = new Uri("/Tits.xaml?size=" + 4, UriKind.Relative)
        }.Show();
```

Looks good.

But the toast will not be showed in my emulator. My code is wrong, or it's problem of emulation? The emulator runs in a restricted mode: my graphics card is old

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can show `ShellToast` only from `Background Agent`. If you trying to show it from foreground app, use Coding4Fun `ToastPrompt` control for this

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt regarding the toast notification. If the app is running both in FG and BG and there is a notification from the BG is it possible to show a toast notification to the user?

Answer (score 0):

U need to have DirectX 10 capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver 
 then emulator will work fine..

Comment: yes, I know it, but I do not work with XNA graphics... how do you think, ShellToast problem only in my emulator, or my code is really wrong? I can't to test it, because all computers in my office the same...

Comment: well i have seen problem in emulator for silverlight applications as well if the driver is not correct. for example you can try following. 1. try to launch any web page from internet explorer in emulator, generally it doesn't work if driver in not compatible. 2. try to launch the camera capture task from code, it also give problem if the driver is not good